# xv6 memory mapping during boot up time

Tags: qemu, xv6

I am reading this book, https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2022/xv6/book-riscv-rev3.pdf

At page 35, "the kernel itself is located at KERNBASE=0x80000000 in both the virtual address space and in physical memory".
I have give QEMU 128M memory, how comes kernel located at 0x80000000 which is 2GB?.

when kernel was loaded, paging mechanism was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

In general in a hardware design there is no requirement that RAM starts at physical address zero. The KERNBASE variable says "where does the RAM start"; it does not say "how big is the RAM". So it's quite possible to have 128MB of RAM that starts at address 0x8000_0000. In this case it would end at address 0x8800_0000. On a different piece of hardware the RAM might start at an entirely different address. Other areas of the physical address space will be used for various devices (like the serial port and the interrupt controller), or may have nothing there at all.

Figure 3.3 in your PDF has the diagram of what physical memory looks like on the board type this kernel wants to run on, as the right hand side diagram. All this (where is the RAM, where are devices, etc) is fixed by the hardware (or by the emulated hardware if you're running on QEMU). The OS can't change this -- it must work with what it has got. It's just a lucky coincidence that the start address of the RAM on this board matches where the OS wants to have its kernel memory start at in the virtual address space.

Answer (score 0):

after reading some docs of QEMU.I think I know why.

In xv6 OS, the "physical memory" is not a real physical memory.
It is a QEMU "physical memory".